# laravel error 1071 key was too long php artisan migrate

Tags: mysql, wamp, php-7, laravel-7

I am using Laravel and I have migration with function:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('subtitle');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->boolean('featured')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
 
        });
    }
```

and when i do `php artisan migrate` on my cmd i get error

```
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 La clé est trop longue. Longueur maximale: 1000 (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_username_unique`(`username`))

  at C:\Users\linda\lynda-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   C:\Users\linda\lynda-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 La clé est trop longue. Longueur maximale: 1000")

  2   C:\Users\linda\lynda-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

I added that to my `AppServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

and this is my `database.php`

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel-ecommerce'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

and my `.env` looks like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel-ecommerce
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I already uncomment the extension ;extension=pdo_mysql in my php.ini I am using WAMP server and already tried this :

```
php artisan cache:clear                    
php artisan config:clear                      
php artisan config:cache
```

when I use mariaDB instead of mysql to create my database I get this error unknown database

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'laravel-ecommerce' inconnue (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel-ecommerce and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Users\linda\lynda-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   C:\Users\linda\lynda-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'laravel-ecommerce' inconnue")

  2   C:\Users\linda\lynda-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel-ecommerce", "root", "", [])
```

Answer (score 34):

This issue might be occurring due to Mariadb or old version of MySQL.

**Solution 1:**

Edit **AppServiceProvider.php** file located at `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and inside the boot method update the default string length:

```
// import builder where defaultStringLength method is defined
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    // Fix for MySQL < 5.7.7 and MariaDB < 10.2.2
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //Update defaultStringLength
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Change Mariadb to mysql, that can also fix the issue.

**Solution 3:**

Inside `config/database.php`, replace this line for mysql

```
'engine' => null',
```

with

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

Hope one of the solution works for you!!

Comment: thanks for your reply but i got an error laravel when i do what you say  like this :                                                                       public function boot()
    {
        defaultStringLength;
    }

Comment: So what worked for you?

Comment: I have already changed to mariaDB but it gives me unknown database

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the version of mysql I hope it will helps someone one day thank you very much

Comment: for laravel 8 the 3 rd solution works fine

Comment: Good Solution for me it works 'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',

Comment: Yes, it is working at my end.

Comment: Solution 3 Works fine for me. Thank you

Comment: Solution3 is worked file for me
update config/database.php file in your laravel project.

YOU CAN SIMPLY UPDATE BELOW CODE:

'engine' => null', 

TO

'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',

Comment: Solution 3 worked using Laravel 10 and MySQL 5.7.43. Thanks.